# Windows phone time to app store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm almost ready with developing my first windows phone app. Can anyone tell me how long it will take to get the app in the store. For ios apps the apps must be approved, that usually takes about a week, for Android it usually takes only a couple of hours. How is it for Windows, does Microsoft approve the app?

Second question: I need a url for the app that refers to the windows app store? 
Is the url known in advance or do I have to publish first before I know the exact app store url of my app?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The answer to the second question actually depends on whether you're submitting a WP8.x package, which goes to the Windows Phone Store, or a Windows 10 package, which goes to the unified Windows Store.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. It's a WP8.x package. Can you tell me what that means for the url?

Answer (score 1):

**First question:** At this moment it is around 3 to 4 hours for a republish and a day for normal a full publication. Just submitted an app last week. These times can change, one of my (new) apps was through the publication in 1 hour. Do keep in mind that it can take some time before you see it in the stores (up to 24 hours)

**Second question:**
When you submit your publication you can see the url of your app.